# Execution failed for task app generate Debug Build Config

Tags: android, firebase, visual-studio, flutter, android-studio

**It gives me this problem and I don't know what to do to solve it, please help.**

(FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.

> Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
> > java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "TODO"

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1).

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml`, look for `TODO` , probably next to `packageName`.

Change it to a number like `1.0.0`.